# SharpDevelop - mixing C# and VB.NET in one project possible?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sharpdevelop

Is is possible to mix C# and VB.NET files in one project when using SharpDevelop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not, at least not directly... you would have to use two compilers to produce one assembly, which is not supported AFAIK. However, if your final goal is to produce a single assembly, you could probably compile two separate assemblies and merge them using [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en)

Comment: It is possible to mix them, IDE does not prevent you but it cannot compile them. I don't care about one assembly, but would like to be able to work in multiple languages within one project.

Comment: You can't do that, however you can have two projects in the same solution

Answer (score -1):

if you are trying to make a vb project, but vb doesnt have the expressions and statements you were looking for, make the two parts seperately, and convert one to the main language the program is made in. to convert it, use sharpdevelop, which is a better version of vs.net